# <read-write buffer ptr 0x00, size 855 at 0x00> python

Tags: python, read-write

So i have a piece of code that looks like this:

`<read-write buffer ptr 0x000000000286AB78, size 855 at 0x000000000286AB40>`

I think it should be an image file :)

I look around and found some links to `memoryview` but looking at the documentation didn't seem like it would be what im after. Of course im rather new to programming.

I would like to save the file to a folder so that i could see the picture. =)

Anyone has idea how to solve this?

you can get access to it with this code, only replace [USERNAME] with your username:

```
import shutil
import os

shutil.copy('C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Favicons','C:\Users\[USERNAME]\Desktop')
con = sqlite3.connect('C:\Users\[USERNAME]\Desktop\Favicons')
cursor = con.cursor()
icon=''
for i in  cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM favicons WHERE id<6 limit 5;"): 
    icon= i,'favicons'
print('\n')
con.close()
os.remove('C:\Users\[USERNAME]\Desktop\Favicons')
```

--- ANSWER ----

```
import StringIO
from PIL import Image
file_ = StringIO.StringIO(icon)
image = Image.open(file_)
size=(128,128)
image=image.resize(size,Image.BILINEAR)
image.save('C:\icon.JPEG', 'JPEG')
```

Thanks for ideas :)

Comment: What do you mean by" you have a piece of code that looks like that"?  Do you mean, you have code that for some reason outputs an object with that representation?

Comment: The code comes from database that im working on. So why it looks like that i don't know, but by the looks of it, its an address to some location :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an answer, but hopefully it is better than nothing. At least until something better comes around.
I think you should take a look at [Python Imaging Library (PIL)](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/).
You should be able to use: `Image.frombuffer(mode, size, data)` [here's](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm) some additional information. You can also try `Image.open()` as I suppose you are getting the image from a sql database?

```
import StringIO

data = read_from_database()

file = StringIO.StringIO(data)

image = Image.open(file)
image.thumbnail((128, 128))

outfile = StringIO.StringIO()
image.save(outfile, "JPEG")
```

Comment: interesting it says it's an PNG file, but when i save it as png it says "Decode Error! invalid or unsupported PNG file". thanks for getting me this far :) didn't know that .write can take objects :)

Comment: i wonder where could i read about this object format .. <read-write buffer ptr .. , size .. at ..>

Comment: for 64bit systems PIL can be downloaded [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)